# Iterate while changing the argument of a function after each iteration (python)

Tags: python

I wrote the following function that changes its argument after every iteration.

```
def thresh (*val):
    for x in val:
        return float(x)/100 * 10000.0

print thresh (15,20)
```

Output: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

```
Desired output: 1500.0, 2000.0
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What calculation produces that output?

Comment: There is no iteration here, and no argument changing.  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to enhance it.

Comment: `def thresh(*val): return (1000., 1500.)` works, at least under the conditions you have supplied :/

Comment: The question was clear to many, I wonder why you guys couldn't figure it out. OdraEncoded and others that responded knew exactly where the problem was and the made effort to solve it immediately. Perhaps you guys should look at their comments. The error I made was, i did not consider val as tuple. Hope this settles it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*val` is a <s>`list`</s> *`tuple`*. `float()` can only parse `str` or `float` not `tuples`.

This snippet iterates through `*val` and returns a list of the computed values.

```
def thresh (*val):
    return [float(one_val)/100 * 10000.0 for one_val in val]
```

Comment: Many thanks @OdraEncoded, I now understand the error i made in my code.

Comment: @Tiger1 If this solved your problem please accept it (big gray check box)  If it didn't solve you problem, but pointed you in the correct direction please write the solution to your problem as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `val` since it has more than one value. Also divide by 100 multiply by 10000 is the same as multiply by 100.

```
def thresh (*val):
     return [x*100.0 for x in val] 

>>> print thresh(15,20)
[1500.0, 2000.0]
```